# Convert List<Object> to List<String> without for?

Tags: java, list

How can I convert a List of Objects to corresponding List of Strings without scanning all elements by for loop?

Comment: Does the list actually contain Strings or do you need to explicitly convert them?

Comment: How can you cast all objects to String ? or typically you need to get all toString() ?

Comment: thanks. the list contains String objects.

Comment: will `do...while` suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
List<String> variable = (List<String>)(List<?>) yourList;
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I need to call toString?

Comment: @HomayounAfshari I am confused. You just said in your comment under question that your list contains Strings. Why would you want to call `toString` on String?

Comment: @Pshemo I just ask to know other cases!

Comment: @HomayounAfshari If by other case you mean that list will contain not only Strings but also other objects that will have to be converted to String (lets say with `toString` method) then you would have to use iterate over list manually (with loop or with some method that will loop it for your) and store String results in separate list (or just use results inside loop if you have to do it just once).

Comment: @HomayounAfshari By the way I would be very grateful if you wouldn't use exclamation mark if it is not required. It represents shouting so when someone reads it it gives same impression as reading TEXT WRITTEN WITH CAPITAL LETTERS or **with bold ones**.

Comment: thanks @Pshemo. I have one other question. Is (List<?>) really needed?

Comment: @HomayounAfshari Yes. You can't directly cast `List<Object>` to `List<String>` because list of objects could have also other objects beside Strings and using `get` on `List<String>` could for example cause casting `Elefant` to `String` which would not be right. But if you explicitly say that you want to cast your list first to list without any specific type `List<?>` compiler later will trust you and let you cast to specific type `List<String>` assuming that you know what type of objects are inside list.

Comment: @HomayounAfshari I've supplied an anwer to your additional question.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you specified that you wanted to call the toString() method. This is possible with guava (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Object, String> objectToString = new Function<Object, String>() {
            public String apply(Object object) {
                return object.toString();
            }
        };
        List<Object> yourList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        yourList.add("foo");
        List<String> strings = Lists.transform(yourList, objectToString);
    }
}
```